# AppleID Two-factor Authentification with Email address

Tags: email, apple-id, two-factor-authentication

Suppose I have 2FA activated for AppleID, and I lose my phone and I need to log in with my AppleID. This becomes further complicated when I travel to another country and have to use another, local phone number for some time.

I wish I could use my email-address for 2FA instead of my phone number.

Is there any way I can log in with my AppleID if I don't have access to my phone number?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can login with your AppleID using any trusted device without having access to your phone number.

The first time you login with your AppleID using an iPhone, iPad, iPod Touch or Mac, you'll be asked if you want to trust the device. This saves data on the device that allows you to login again without having to your phone number at all.

When you need to login with your AppleID you can use any of the trusted devices to generate the necessary six-digit verification code. So if you're logging on to a new, untrusted device, you can use the code shown on your Mac, iPad or another device as verification. You do not have to use your phone number at all.

The trusted phone number is only used if you cannot access of your trusted devices. You can potentially use a VoIP phone number as the trusted phone number (make sure to check that the specific VoIP service works for this purpose), if you having problem carrying your ordinary number with you when you travel. However, normally it is not problem taking your cell phone and phone services to other countries.

Regarding your frustration with "why not email": Only Apple can really know why Apple did what Apple did. However, the point of 2-factor authentication is to ensure that two different factors are used when authentication - these factors are commonly named "something you know", "something you have" and "something you are".

For many people their email-account will be behind the same username and password as the AppleID they want to protect with 2FA - therefore using email is not a good idea there. In addition, quite a few will have their email protected by only a username and a password - which similar to your AppleID username and password is "something you know" - which means that you then only have 1-factor authentication.

You could easily argue that Apple should support other methods for the second factor - such as for example TOTP tokens. However, we cannot know why Apple has chosen not to do so. It is really speculation at that point.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent treatment of a very broad initial version of the question. I’ve also removed a bit more of the “hypothetical” from the post. This becomes more of a practical problem with some minor edits once you cleaned up the question. Thank you very much.

Comment: The reason Apple does not allow Email is because it only allows a domestic AppleID account tied to a physical device that one person has, to ensure businesses don't just apply for multiple AppleIDs and has an ability to manage them from 1 email account.  This forces businesses with devices used by multiple people, to use the business ApplID and the $5-$7 per MONTH per DEVICE charge.  Nearly as much as buying a copy of Windows per year, just so you can access the App store apps.  I am surprised this is allowed as it 's predatory practices and illegal under consumer law in many countries.

Comment: @JamesGardiner You have that misunderstood completely. You can manage multiple AppleIDs from one device without any problems. You can set up a single iPhone or iPad to show verification codes for many AppleIDs. There’s no 5-7$ charge anywhere.

Comment: @jksoegaard Sorry, no, I was on the phone to apple a few days ago.  You have a limit of 5 devices ONLY on a domestic AppleID account.  We could get a free business AppleID account and add as many devices as we want, BUT if we want to use the App store, then they have to pay for these special app management access as $5-7 per month per device managed.  So, No, Small businesses just put up with the difficulty of many different account on many different devices over paying $60-80 per year, just so you can run an application you got from AppStore.

Comment: @JamesGardiner As I said, the guy on the phone was probably mistaken, or you something has been confused. It is definitely NOT the case that you cannot have multiple devices generating 2FA codes for the same AppleID. From the sound of it, it doesn't sound like you're actually wanting to generate 2FA codes - it sounds more like you want to pay for an app once and install it on 50 company devices for free?

Answer (score 3):

Keep in mind SMS is a fallback from trusted device push notifications. You don’t even need an SMS message unless you can not / do not choose to have trusted devices with you that use network based Apple push notification services (APNS).

1. Go all in on trusted devices if you can - avoid SMS entirely.
2. Choose a dual sim phone if you can so you can layer both lines when you travel or add a short term number.
3. Many carriers allow SMS to forward to a watch or iPad or computer so that the delivery is network based like the Apple trusted device notification path.
4. Add your new number as a trusted phone number when you need that extra flexibility.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204915

You don’t have to remove your primary or depend on SMS only would be my recommendation unless/until Apple adds new methods of verifying it’s you when you want to sign in to a service from abroad.

Comment: This answer is flawed because it is based on a misconception that the verification codes are being delivered using push notifications (APNS).